# Каким образом выбирается файл dll

Tags: .net, dll

Максимально абстрактно:

1. Есть папка в которой лежат несколько файлов dll.
2. Есть приложение, которое использует `nlog.dll` для ведения собственных логов. Это приложение удаляет все файлы по маске `*.dll` в папке откуда оно запущено. Nlog этой программы слит в один exe файл с помощью **Costura.Fody**

Если положить программу в папку, то все нормально до тех пор пока в папке нет файла `nlog.dll` - в этом случае ругается что нет доступа и файл остается. По диспетчеру получается что эту dll использует как раз само приложение, причем даже если файл будет называться `NLog.old - копия (2).old.dll`, то этот файл будет подгружен программой и не удалится.

Как задается выбор файла dll который должен использоваться? почему берется даже файл `nlog.dll` имя которого не совсем подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что имя файла можно сменить, но необходимые метаданные (первоначальное имя, с которым сборка собрана) все равно внутри останутся. У Рихтера в главе про развертывание этот случай описывается.